# Problem with 'exists' validation in Laravel when the input is an array

Tags: laravel, validation, exists

The file here `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php` and the method `validateExists` returns error

> Array to string conversion

when user inputs are like this below:

```
array:2 [
    0 => array:1 [
        'key' => 'value'
    ]
    1 => array:1 [
        'key' => 'value'
    ]
]
```

This array goes into the variable `$value` on line 655 in this file.

Is it a real laravel bug there?

**Edit**

My Validation:

```
'cars.*.brand' => [
    'exists:my_table,id',
]
```

Comment: You should show how your validation looks like.

Comment: show your dd($request->all()); when you have error

Comment: The multidimensional array in the question is the output of `$value`. I put it inside try catch and that array printed out in catch part.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of info to give you an answer, but have you tried:

`'cars.*.brand' => 'exists:my_table,id'`

Comment: I didn't get what the differences there are between your validation and mine!

Comment: In your example you provide the validation rule "exists:my_table,id" in an array, while I provide it as a string. The error you get is "Array to string conversion" therefore this might be the fix.